# subContentNavigationController Displays previous UIView Content

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am fairly new to Xcode and I have been trying to resolve this issue for the past 2 days.

I have a menu (tableView), which opens up a submenu (tableview). Selecting an item in the submenu opens a contentView for that specific item.

The first selection works fine, eg:

Customers > Customer1 > Customer1 Details Nav > Customer1 Details

now if I change the selection in the first menu, it will display the navigationController for the Produc1 Details view but display what seems to be a snapshot of the Customer1 Details view, eg:

Products > Product1 > Product1 Details Nav > Customer1 Details

Bellow is the code used to navigate through the menus:

**MAINMENU**

```
 if( [string isEqualToString:@"Customers"] ){    
            [self.contentNavigationController.view removeFromSuperview];
             _subContentView.hidden = YES;

            _subMenuView.hidden = NO;

            CustomersController *cc = (CustomersController*)((UINavigationController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomersNav"]).viewControllers[0];
            cc.selectorDelegate = self;
            cc.isSelector = NO;

            [self.subMenuNavigationController pushViewController:cc animated:YES];
            [self.subMenuNavigationController popToViewController:cc animated:NO];

            NSLog(@"%d",self.subMenuNavigationController.viewControllers.count);

            _contentView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(540, 748);
        }
```

**SUBMENU**

```
-(void)customersChangedSelectedCustomerTo:(NSDictionary*)dictionary{

    _subContentView.hidden=YES;
    _contentView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(860, 748);

     CustomerDetailsController *cdc = (CustomerDetailsController*)((UINavigationController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomerDetailsNav"]).viewControllers[0];

    [cdc setCustomerID:[dictionary[@"CustomerID"] intValue]];
    //try
    [self.subContentNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    //try
    [self.subContentNavigationController pushViewController:cdc animated:YES];
    [self.subContentNavigationController popToViewController:cdc animated:NO];

    [self.subContentNavigationController setViewControllers:@[ cdc ]];

    _subContentView.hidden = NO;

}
```

Below are 2 screenshots displaying what is happening. The green and red rectangles are there to show you guys the flow of the menus.

I would post images, but I don't have enough rep.

http://i61.tinypic.com/tag76u.png

http://i59.tinypic.com/k4bko2.png